# How to reduce TTFB for PHP on Apache / Windows?

Tags: php, windows, apache, wamp

I remarked that a simple PHP script takes 1.01 second TTFB (Time to first byte) on my local Apache/PHP configuration, whereas a simple HTML takes only 21 milliseconds.

The script is as follow :

```
<?php
echo('done');
?>
```

Apache is 2.4 and PHP is 5.3.1 - It is on Windows 7, with a Wamp configuration : server Uniform server 8.3.1

The TTFB is readable on this screencopy :

[image: The TTFB is visible on this screencopy (Chrome)]

Is it possible to reduce this time ? I am wondering what the server is doing during this second.

Comment: Are you accessing the local page via `localhost` or IP address?

Comment: I am accessing via  `localhost`. But as explained in the question, the time is only 21 ms for a HTML content, also accessed via `localhost`.

Comment: Well, there is probably something rotten inside the "Uniform Server". I would suggest at least updating to more recent version (PHP 5.6 or preferably PHP 7).

Comment: For the moment, I am stuck to 5.3 because the link to some production sites. However I tried with a more recent version of Uniform Server (11.7.3 with PHP 5.4) and I saw that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This minimal second of TTFB was caused by a debug extension I added some weeks ago : the two following lines of `php.ini` call this extension.

```
[CLDbg]
extension=php_cl_dbg_5_3_VC9.dll
clport=9000
```

This debug extension provides a debugger function (which works fine) with the CodeLobster IDE. There is a network delay due to the call to the debugging port. The uniform server is innocent :-) and works fine, too.